# Inserting a Ratio field into a Pandas Series

Tags: python, pandas, series

I get a Pandas series:

```
 countrypat = asiaselect.groupby('Country')['Pattern'].value_counts().groupby(level=0).head(3)
```

The output looks like this:

```
China      abc                1055
           def                 778
           ghi                 612
Malaysia   def                 554
           abc                 441
           ghi                 178
[...]
```

How to insert a new column (do I have to make this a dataframe) containing the ratio of the numeric column to the sum of the numbers for that country.  Thus for China I would want a new column and the first row would contain (1055/(1055+778+612)).   I have tried unstack() and to_df() but was unsure of the next steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a dataframe on my side, but excluded the `.head(3)` of your assigment:

```
countrypat = asiaselect.groupby('Country')['Pattern'].value_counts().groupby(level=0)
```

The following will give you the proportions with a simple apply to your groupby object:

```
countrypat.apply(lambda x: x / float(x.sum()))
```

The only 'problem' is that doing so returns you a series, so I would stock the intermediate results in two different series and combine them at the end:

```
series1 = asiaselect.groupby('Country')['Pattern'].value_counts()
series2 = asiaselect.groupby('Country')['Pattern'].value_counts().groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: x / float(x.sum()))
pd.DataFrame([series1, series2]).T

China    abc       1055.0  0.431493
         def        778.0  0.318200
         ghi        612.0  0.250307
Malaysia def        554.0  0.472293
         abc        441.0  0.375959
         ghi        178.0  0.151748
```

As to get the top three rows, you can simply add a `.groupby(level=0).head(3)` to each series1 and series2

```
series1_top = series1.groupby(level=0).head(3)
series2_top = series2.groupby(level=0).head(3)
pd.DataFrame([series1_top, series2_top]).T
```

I tested with a dataframe containing more than 3 rows, and it seems to work. Started with the following df:

```
China     abc        1055
          def         778
          ghi         612
          yyy           5
          xxx           3
          zzz           3
Malaysia  def         554
          abc         441
          ghi         178
          yyy           5
          xxx           3
          zzz           3
```

and ends like this:

```
China    abc       1055.0  0.429560
         def        778.0  0.316775
         ghi        612.0  0.249186
Malaysia def        554.0  0.467905
         abc        441.0  0.372466
         ghi        178.0  0.150338
```

Comment: Let's say each country had, for example, 10 rows.  How to get the head(3) for each country?

Comment: You mean you would like only the proportion to be calculated on the sum of the 3 highest numbers? (head(3))

Comment: Let's say I have 10 rows per country where the ratios sum to 1.  How to report only the top 3 rows per country, understanding the ratios won't sum to 1?  (using all the rows to calculate the ratio but just filtering the output to the leaders) ?

Comment: I just edited the answer to resolve your issue with head(3)